# Wordpress. Добавление языкового префикса в ЧПУ

Tags: wordpress, чпу, плагин

Подскажите, кто работал с Wordpress. Как можно через плагин изменить постоянную ссылку, чтоб она была вида `/%lang%/%postname%/`. В ссылке на пост можно пока чтоб отображался префикс `/en/`. Этот префикс должен игнорироваться системой, т.е. должны отображаться те посты, которые раньше отображались без префикса.

Например: `mysite.com/en/mypost/` отображало то-же самое, что раньше `mysite.com/mypost/`.